# Unable to find the URL to invoke the application; getting a 404 response

Tags: java, http-status-code-404

I deployed an application with a ear file and am unable to invoke the application with below URL

```
http://localhost:8989/RetailProducts/faces/eBusiness.jsp
```

I created the dynamic project and did all the stuff for UI. I then created the EJB project and completed all the stuff required for EJB.

When I deploy above modules independently on the server it is working fine with above URL.

When I create new enterprise project and create the EAR file I'm getting 404 response. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the image of package structure.

[image]

This is the message getting on the console

> SEVERE: PWC6117: File
>   "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\retailproduct\docroot\RetailProducts\faces\eBusiness.jsp"
>   not found

Comment: Are u getting any unusual errors while deploying the server of while running the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open eBussiness.jsp page, right click on it, then choose `Run`.

Check the URL on the browser now.

Hope you get it.

Comment: iam getting below message in server console <br> SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\retailproduct\docroot\RetailProducts\faces\eBusiness.jsp" not found

Comment: Even while trying to run from the page?

Comment: Can you edit your question including the message receiving on the server console?